# Try to compare 2 methods to implement bounded blocking queue

Tags: multithreading

bounded blocking queue is famous, of course. There are mostly 2 methods to implement it. I try to understand which way is better:
Method 1: use counting semaphore

```
void *producer(void *arg) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    sem_wait(&empty);           
    sem_wait(&mutex);           
    put(i);                     
    sem_post(&mutex);           
    sem_post(&full);            
}
}
void *consumer(void *arg) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        sem_wait(&full);            
        sem_wait(&mutex);           
        int tmp = get();            
        sem_post(&mutex);           
        sem_post(&empty);           
        printf("%d\n", tmp);
    }
}
```

Method 2: classic monitor pattern

```
class BoundedBuffer {
  private:
    int buffer[MAX];
    int fill, use;
    int fullEntries;
    pthread_mutex_t monitor; // monitor lock
    pthread_cond_t empty;
    pthread_cond_t full;

  public:
    BoundedBuffer() {
        use = fill = fullEntries = 0;
    }
    void produce(int element) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&monitor);
        while (fullEntries == MAX) 
            pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &monitor); 
        //do something
        pthread_cond_signal(&full);             
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&monitor);
    }

    int consume() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&monitor);
        while (fullEntries == 0)   
            pthread_cond_wait(&full, &monitor);           
        //do something
        pthread_cond_signal(&empty);            
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&monitor);
        return tmp;                
    }
}
```

I understand the 2nd method can solve a lot of other problems. But how to compare these 2 methods? Looks like they can both fulfill the task. 
Is there any link on detailed comparision?
Appreciate your help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big difference between those two methods is that the first one does not use pthread_ specific functions (semaphores are not part of pthread) and as such is not guaranteed to work in multithreaded enviornment.

In particular, semaphores do not protect memory ordering, so things written in one thread might not be readable on another. Mutexes are suitable for multi-thread message queue.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that POSIX has semaphores, and that all the OS I've used have a sufficiency of barriers around semaphore operations.

Comment: POSIX, of course, has semaphores. It is just not pthreads. And no, semaphores do not have barriers. They can not have a proper barriers built on them, as they can be released from a thread/process which does not own them.

Comment: Hi Sergey. Thanks a lot for your comment. Can you explain more about "memory ordering"? What is ordered? Looks like you are saying threads will not share memory? But if the memory is inside a function surely it is not shared, right? Thanks.

Comment: @user2988877, this is a huge topic. You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering